# Hive Create Table query for complex Json structure

Tags: json, hive, amazon-athena

Using AWS Athena I want to convert the following JSON to a table.

```
"Cakes": {
"48630ca6": {
  "key1": "NONE",
  "key2": "4863dsads0ca6",
  "key3": [
    {
      "x": 82,
      "y": 82
    }
  ],
  "key4": "a"
},
"56d5886b": {
  "key1": "NONE",
  "key2": "df",
  "key3": [
    {
      "x": 84,
      "y": 84
    }
  ],
  "key4": "b"
},
...
```

},

The issue is I dont know the 2nd level key i.e 48630ca6,56d5886b etc The 2nd level can have many keys and I don't know how to map it to a struct with hive without knowing the length or value beforehand. Can it be casted to an array ?

Comment: do you mean in `56d5886b` there are chances that there could be only 1 key or more than 4, and these applies to other object as well.

Comment: I meant the level after cakes i.e 48630ca6, 56d5886b, the next could be 66d8974c and so on.

Comment: If the data can be modified, you can have the keys `48630ca6` and `56d5886b` as arrays. Then `Cakes` could be an array of json objects and you just need to specify `array<struct<json_structure_here>>` while creating the table.